# Symfony 4 - LiipImagine - Listener delete all my directory (cache clear listener)

Tags: php, symfony, caching, listener, liipimaginebundle

I have a symfony 4 project with a User entity that has a relationship with an Avatar entity (images uploaded with VichUploaderBundle).

**In Avatar.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 * 
 * @Assert\Image(
 *  mimeTypes="image/jpeg")
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="avatar", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
 * 
 * @var File|null
 */
private $imageFile;
```

**In User.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Avatar", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $avatar;
```

I have a profile page to edit a user's data (name, surname, mail, avatar).
In this page, I use LiipImagineBundle to display the current avatar in a certain dimension.

When the user edits his profile, I wish a listener can check is there are changes in the avatar. In which case, it deletes the old media / cache.

So I created a Listener for that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listener;

use App\Entity\Avatar;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\CacheManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Templating\Helper\UploaderHelper;

class ImageCacheSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{

    /**
     * CacheManager
     *
     * @var CacheManager
     */
    private $cacheManager;

    /**
     * UploaderHelper
     *
     * @var UploaderHelper
     */
    private $uploaderHelper;

    public function __construct(CacheManager $cacheManager, UploaderHelper $uploaderHelper)
    {
        $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
        $this->uploaderHelper = $uploaderHelper;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'preRemove',
            'preUpdate'
        ];
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof Avatar) {
            return;
        }

        $this->cacheManager->remove($this->uploaderHelper->asset($entity, 'imageFile'));
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        dump($args->getEntity());
        dump($args->getObject());

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof Avatar) {
            return;
        }

        if ($entity->getImageFile() instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $this->cacheManager->remove($this->uploaderHelper->asset($entity, 'imageFile'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Services.yaml:**

```
  App\Listener\ImageCacheSubscriber:
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

But when I change my avatar, the listener removes the entire folder containing the avatars in the media.

And he provokes me this error:

> Failed to remove directory
>   "C:\Users\user\Desktop\congesTest2/public/media/cache/avatar_big\files":
>   rmdir(C:\Users\user\Desktop\congesTest2/public/media/cache/avatar_big\files):
>   Directory not empty.

I don't understand why ... :'(

EDIT:

I update my function preUpdate() to postUpdate() :

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'preRemove',
            'postUpdate'
        ];
    }
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        dump($args->getEntity());

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof Avatar) {
            return;
        }

        if ($entity->getImageFile() instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $this->cacheManager->remove($this->uploaderHelper->asset($entity, 'imageFile'));
        }
    }
```

And now, if I make a dump of :

```
    dd($this->uploaderHelper->asset($entity, 'imageFile'));
```

I've :

> "/images/avatar/avatar3.jpg"
>   And this is the good path ! On the other hand, the image is not removed from the cache! The remove () function does not seem to give anything it's amazing

With the dump of the entity, I saw that the file was no longer an UploadedFile but a File simply. Whereas before it seemed like an UploadedFile. So I changed the line

```
if ($entity->getImageFile() instanceof UploadedFile)
```

by

```
if ($entity->getImageFile() instanceof File)
```

But the image is still not deleted from the cache.

In my opinion, since this is a postUpdate, it removes the new cache image, not the old one. But since the user is redirected to the same page, he delivers it immediately after caching. (EDIT : No I did a test, the image is not even removed from the cache)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of listening to Doctrine events, you can listen to the `vich_uploader.pre_remove` event. This will ensure you get the old image that needs to be removed every time. First, make sure your VichUploader config is set to delete files on update and remove. This is the default.

```
# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml

vich_uploader:
    mappings:
        avatar:
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/avatar'
            uri_prefix: 'uploads/avatar'

            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

Now you need to create the listener.

```php
// src/EventListener/ImageCacheSubscriber.php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\CacheManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Event\Event;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Event\Events;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Storage\StorageInterface;

class ImageCacheSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $storage;
    private $cacheManager;

    public function __construct(StorageInterface $storage, CacheManager $cacheManager)
    {
        $this->storage = $storage;
        $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
    }

    public function onRemove(Event $event)
    {
        $path = $this->storage->resolveUri($event->getObject(), $event->getMapping()->getFilePropertyName());
        $this->cacheManager->remove($path);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [Events::PRE_REMOVE => 'onRemove'];
    }
}
```

When any VichUploader asset is removed, this listener will attempt to remove it from the cache for all filters. You can specify specific filters in the `CacheManager::remove()` method if you would like. You could also only remove the cache for specific entities by checking the instance of `$event->getObject()`.

This also makes a few assumptions about your LiipImagine config. If you're using the default loader and cache resolver, this should work. If you're using a custom loader or resolver, you may need to modify this listener to your needs.

```
# config/packages/liip_imagine.yaml

liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: '%kernel.project_dir%/public'
                cache_prefix: 'media/cache'

    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root:
                    - '%kernel.project_dir%/public'

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~

        # Your filters...
```

If you're using Symfony Flex, you're done. Otherwise, make sure to register the listener as a service.

```
# config/services.yaml

services:
    # ...
    App\EventListener\ImageCacheSubscriber:
        arguments: ['@vich_uploader.storage.file_system', '@liip_imagine.cache.manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, it seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using VichUploaderBundle it should not be needed to create your own listener. Make sure the lifecycle events are properly configured and Vich should take care of deleting old images.

```
# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml or app/config/config.yml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/products'

            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#step-3-configure-the-lifecycle-events-optional-step

Comment: That's not a problem, if I delete an image or update it, it will be updated in my directory containing my files. But the problem is on LiipImagineBundle. The cached image is not deleted

Comment: Ok my bad, what is the output of  $this->uploaderHelper->asset($entity, 'imageFile')

Comment: Wow ! It returns "null". It's strange because if I dump ($entity), I've the "Avatar" entity

Comment: You might want to look into that first, maybe your Vich config is off?

Comment: Normally not my VichUploader config is OK. The delete_on_update and delete_on_remove work so there should be no problem

Comment: What kind of storage are you using? Is it the FileSystemStorage?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But yes my images are saved on my computer locally in the folder / public for the moment.

Comment: Can you try to debug the function: resolveUri in Vich\UploaderBundle\Storage\FileSystemStorage ? That one should be called when you call uploaderHelper->asset

Comment: I am beginer in Symfony, how can I do this please ?

Comment: Open that file from your vendor folder and use the dump statement to dump the output of the variables inside.

Comment: Okay, when I dump the $uploadDir, I've an empty value. But when I dump the output : "sprintf('%s/%s', $mapping->getUriPrefix(), $uploadDir . $name);", I've this : "/images/avatar/avatar.jpg"

Comment: And are you sure it outputs null in your own class, did you dump it before or after executing the remove method?

Comment: Yes I just retest and I made a dd ($ this-> uploaderHelper-> asset ($ entity, 'imageFile', Avatar :: class)) ;, and it is well null

Comment: Can you try and change preUpdate to postUpdate, so listen to the post event instead?

Comment: Where is the cache of your image stored? Is it in a unique folder per entity?

Comment: With VichUploader, my images are on Public/images/avatar.
With LiipImagine, my images, on the cache, are on public\media\cache\avatar_big\images\avatar

(I've three avatar sizes with LiipImagine : avatar_big, avatar_small, avatar_medium, so the path is different for each type of avatar ).
So for now I only have one entity that is cached from LiipImagine, but I'm going to add more